# what was the reason to get (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:9000 error?

Tags: apache, webserver, httpd.conf

I am trying to configure two sites on different ports of same ip address.

```
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:9000
```

I am getting error . what is reason to this error and how to solve this error ?

my `httpd.conf` file is

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost 192.168.2.10:80
<VirtualHost 192.168.2.10:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/white-socks
ServerName www.white-socks.com
</VirtualHost>
Listen 9000
NameVirtualHost 192.168.2.10:9000
<VirtualHost 192.168.2.10:9000>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/black-socks
ServerName www.black-socks.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I am getting error like below.

```
[root@ram conf]# service httpd start
Starting httpd: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for ram
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:9000
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:9000
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                                                           [FAILED]
[root@ram conf]#
```

what i have to do fix this ?

Comment: Read [bind(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html)

Answer (score 1):

Many a times this error occurs if you are using **Selinux** ( Only for RedHat base OS) and it is not configured properly. Try disabling Selinux by `setenforce 0` or if you don't want to disable selinux than properly configure selinux by :-

```
semanage port -l | grep http
semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 9000
```

Restart your apache server and check.

Also you can check the netstat command ouput to see if ports are already been used or not.

`netstat -tunalp | grep :9000`

`netstat -tunalp | grep :80`

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues that need to be resolved:

1. Permissions and access to httpd
2. Port access

---

1. The first issue involves ownership it could be that your server hasn't the right permissions and you need to chmod a folder (obviously **not** your document root or any folder that users connecting to the webserver have access to).  To check if this is the issue run in terminal

---

```
sudo httpd
```

sudo allows you to run commands as root.  If it works as normal then its a permissions issue.

2. Only one server can access one port it is assigned.  If another server accesses the same port, it will be denied access to that port.  So if you have two servers they cannot operate on the same port simultaneously. You will need to change the appropriate configuration files that limit the scope of your server that is accessing port 80, 8080 or 9000.  If you have a default apache server (as is sometimes the case in MacOS) then you will need to limit its scope or disable it entirely.

---

```
sudo bash -x /usr/sbin/apachectl -k stop
```

Will stop the default server in MacOS

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

Will stop future running at startup